# C# - I'm having problems overwriting data in text file from Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm creating a small program that can save website urls/links into a listbox. From there, I can save the contents of the listbox onto a text file. That text file is then saved to a folder on my desktop that was prematurely made for the program. The application can open a text file and display the contents to the listbox as well as create and save a new text file with. My problem is how would I overwrite the text file properly.

This is the code I have for the Save Toolbox button:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    string line = "";

    if (File.Exists(path)) //the path string is a folder on my desktop
    {
        FileStream fstream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);
        while (line != null)
        {
            using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(fstream))
            {
                foreach (object item in WebListBox.Items)
                    write.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save as Text File";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (FileStream S = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(S))
                {
                    foreach (var items in WebListBox.Items)
                        st.WriteLine(items.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after I create the text file using the Save As ToolBar button,  the compiler seemingly ignores the code in my if statement and assumes that I want to always create a new text file to save to. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "glances" as in the compiler skipping the if statement and proceeding to read the else statement. Sorry for the wording. And yes, I've been debugging this code but I still haven't found any possible solution.

Comment: Note: You are showing your ShowDialog twice.  In the first branch, your "line" is never anything except an empty string.

Comment: Is `path` the path to the file or is it to a folder? Per MSDN about [`File.Exists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.File.Exists);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1): "If `path` describes a directory, this method returns `false`."

Comment: It leads to a folder. Then I have my code check the folder to see if a file with the same name exists, if it does it overwrites it.

Comment: Your while loop never exits, and it should throw an exception because the fstream is never closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple revisions and outside help, I figured out the problem. The file name I was trying to retrieve from my folder directory was null, so nothing would be saved. Therefore what I did was I would retrieve the file name from the form itself if it was last opened/saved onto the form.

[Here's a picture to help visualize. Any text file that was last opened or saved, it would display it here and compiler would use that path in my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxs8R.jpg)

Using the full path of the file instead of the shorten one, I would overwrite the contents of the file to that path. Doing this also allows me save my files anywhere on my computer.

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
                var fileNameAndPath = filedisplaylabel.Text; 

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((fileNameAndPath)))
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filedisplaylabel.Text = Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName); 
                fileNameAndPath = filedisplaylabel.Text;
            }
        }                        
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(fileNameAndPath,
                    FileMode.Open,
                        FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(fstream))
                    {
                        foreach (var item in WebListBox.Items)
                            write.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                        write.Close();
                    }
                    fstream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found error");
            }                                                                                 
    }
```